# Referencing a URL that includes a hyphen (NOT a dash)

Tags: html, url, ascii

I ran into a website that used a hyphen (not a dash) to build it's URL. I want to link to this website from another HTML document using the following code:

```
<a href="http://www.interskill.com/course-catalog/TSO-ISPF-Managing-Data-Files-and-Definitions-with–TSO-ISPF.html">The Course</a>
```

Difficult to see, but the hyphen is the 14th character from the right in the href. (Immediately before the second TSO abbreviation.)

Is there a way to reference this character properly using an ASCII escape code similar to a `%20` for a space?

Or am I stuck with sending the other web-dev kindly asking them to fix the problem? :-)

Comment: http://www.degraeve.com/reference/urlencoding.php

Comment: it works fine for me when i add it in my website

Comment: @Andy: There is no hyphen there.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, everyone.

I think I am up against an "em-dash" or an "en-dash" vs a "figure dash" according to the definitions found in [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash).

Assuming that's the case, is there a way to rewrite the URL using either the HTML character entity reference `&mdash;` or the numeric character reference `&#x2014;` instead?

Comment: @StevenRyan: It's an en-dash: http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2013/index.htm Although both `&ndash;` and `&#2013;` seems to work, you should be better of sticking to the UTF-8 encoding, as that is the encoding that the RFC standards says that the URL should use. Using the HTML entities means that the browser has to encode the character before requesting the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You would use `%e2%80%93` to encode that hyphen character:

```
<a href="http://www.interskill.com/course-catalog/TSO-ISPF-Managing-Data-Files-and-Definitions-with%e2%80%93TSO-ISPF.html">The Course</a>
```

I used this C# code to find out the encoding:

```
Console.WriteLine(HttpUtility.UrlEncode("–"));
```

Comment: Would also like to know this.... I inserted the reference into my web page and it worked like a charm. Marking as "accepted" with my gratitude @Guffa.